# Как перенести текст на новую строку java

Tags: java, android

Должно быть

1

2

//

```
String text = "";

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    
            Boolean loadUr1_1_v1;
    
            loadUr1_1_v1 = (settings.getBoolean("loadUr1_1_v1", false));
            editor.apply();
            if (loadUr1_1_v1 == true) {
                text=text+"1";
                textView1.setText(text);
    
            } else {}
    
            Boolean loadUr1_1_v2;
    
            loadUr1_1_v2 = (settings.getBoolean("loadUr1_1_v2", false));
            editor.apply();
            if (loadUr1_1_v2 == true) {
                text=text+"2";
                textView1.setText(text);
    
            } else {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строку просто добавляете спец. символ

```
text = "1" + "\n"
```